# Apache Virtual Host HTTPS Site Not Reachable

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, https, sftp

Firstly, my HTTPS site setup using Virtual Host Redirect is working fine. But, after i try to add restrictive SFTP user by target user home directory into web directory of my HTTPS site with the following command

```
useradd -G crmadmin ftpuser1
usermod -a -G www-data ftpuser1
```

and then i append following to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User ftpuser1
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I continue run following command

```
usermod -d /var/www/crmsite ftpuser1
service ssh restart
```

After that, all of my user sftp access to the server has result connection refused. Then, i undo change made to /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Then, the sftp access of all sftp user is working fine. Then, i find my HTTPS site has down, site not reachable.

After that, i try to run and change home directory of the sftp user  and run following command

```
usermod -d /home/ftpuser1 ftpuser1
```

My HTTPS site still not reachable. This is my configuration of Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kg.mycrm.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mycrm.com
    Redirect permanent / https://kg.mycrm.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName kg.mycrm.com
    ServerAdmin kg@mycrm.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crmsite

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example/examplecert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example/examplekey.key
</VirtualHost>
```